Trading View - Display indicator only on the symbol it was started on
I have an indicator in Pine Script that analyse data specific to the symbol of the chart it is displayed on. When I change the symbol the indicator is not applicable anymore and it should not be displayed anymore.
As an example, if I draw a line on a BTCUSD chart and switch to an ETHUSD chart, the line no longer shows, but I than switch back to the BTCUSD chart the line is drawn again. I need the same kind of limitation for my indicator.
Note: I don't want to limit the indicator to only draw in a BTCUSD chart. If it was started on ETHUSD, it must draw on ETHUSD, if it was started on BTCUSD, it must draw on BTCUSD. In fact, if possible I want to be able to have multiple instances of the indicator at the same time but with different input parameters, one drawing on BTCUSD and another on ETHUSD.
